# Initializing custom view with custom initializer (additional data)

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to initialize a custom view (which extends LinearLayout) and pass additional arguments?
I would like to set a boolean to display or not display certain info.

Now I've got something like this:
`customButton = findViewById(R.id.customButton);`
inside CustomButton class there is a boolean varialbe `shouldShowText` which I would like to be set by the user when initializing the view.
Inside my custom button (LinearLayout) there all three constructors: with Context, Context and AtributeSet and Context, AttributeSet and int. Everywhere I'm calling my init but I don't know how to pass additional data.

Answer (score 1):

You can add you custom Layout in your xml like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.CustomLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/customButton"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

</com.example.CustomLayout>
```

And in Java code you can call like this,

```
CustomLayout customButton = (CustomLayout)findViewById(R.id.customButton);
// and you can call your method like this.
customButton.shouldShowText([your boolean]);
```

Edited:
Your Custom class

```
public class CustomButton extends LinearLayout  {
     public void shouldShowText(boolean showText) {
         // Do your action here
     }
}
```

Comment: hmm, but this involves creating new method? Something like: `void shouldShowText(boolean should){...}`? Now I've got a variable: `public class CustomButton extends LinearLayout { public boolean shouldShowText ... }`

Comment: ok, that's not exactly what I was looking for but thanks. Another question - how to make implementing of this function required by this user? Should I create an abstract class?

Comment: then what you looking for..?

Comment: do you want to set it from xml..?

Comment: It's ok - it works but I wanted to do it in one line - initialize and change my variable in the same statement. What about requiring this `shouldShowText` method?

Comment: What about requiring this shouldShowText method, I don't understand what is this mean.

Comment: I mean that if the user initializes the `customButton = findViewById(R.id.customButton)` then the method `shouldShowText` MUST be implemented, otherwise the app won't compile.

Comment: We can't force the user to use that method, you can use default fallback in your custom class. I think for your case you can add custom attributes in **attr** and ask the user to set from XML.